# Expanding List UITableView is duplicating

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

I want to create a dynamic table that expands another data when it selected.

I've follow this tutorial  **https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ClrSpJ3txAs**  but i cant make dynamic (each data is duplicating)

Here's what i want to make [image: What i want]

And here's what i've been made
[image: This is what I’ve been create]

The data itself is duplicating and i dont know how to fix it because when i change some code inside tableView(), it'll crash when i select it or when i'm segue into this view.

Here's my code:

```
import UIKit
import PopupDialog


struct cellData {

      var isOpened            = Bool()
      var title             = [String]()
      var sectionData = [String]()
}

class TutorialBankTableViewController: UITableViewController {

      var user = DBManager.instance.getUserProfile()
      var tableViewData = [cellData]()
      var extendedData = ""
      var sendTitleNameForGettingExtendedData = ""
      var arrayextendedData: [String] = []
      var titleName: [String] = []

      override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()


          reloadTableView()

          // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
      }

      func reloadTableView() {


          if titleName.isEmpty == true {

              requestTitleName()

          } else {

              tableViewData = [cellData(isOpened: false, title: titleName, sectionData: arrayextendedData),
                               cellData(isOpened: false, title: titleName, sectionData: arrayextendedData),
                               cellData(isOpened: false, title: titleName, sectionData: arrayextendedData),
                               cellData(isOpened: false, title: titleName, sectionData: arrayextendedData),
                               cellData(isOpened: false, title: titleName, sectionData: arrayextendedData)]

              DispatchQueue.main.async { self.tableView.reloadData() }

          }

      }




      override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
          super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
          // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
      }

      // MARK: - Table view data source

      override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
          // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
          return tableViewData.count
      }

      override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
          // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
          if tableViewData[section].isOpened {

              return (tableViewData[section].sectionData.count + 1)
          }
          return 1
      }

      override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

          if indexPath.row == 0 {
              guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") else {
                  return UITableViewCell()
              }
              cell.textLabel?.text = tableViewData[indexPath.section].title[indexPath.row]
              return cell
          } else {
              guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") else {
                  return UITableViewCell()
              }

              self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 16, 0, 0);

              cell.textLabel?.text = tableViewData[indexPath.section].sectionData[indexPath.row - 1]
              return cell

          }
      }

      override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

          if indexPath.row == 0 {

              if tableViewData[indexPath.section].isOpened {

                  let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow //optional, to get from any UIButton for example

                  let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!) as! UITableViewCell

                  print(currentCell.textLabel!.text)

                  sendTitleNameForGettingExtendedData = currentCell.textLabel!.text!

                  requestExtendedData()

              } else {

                  tableViewData[indexPath.section].isOpened = true

              }
                  let sections = IndexSet(integer: indexPath.section)
                  tableView.reloadSections(sections, with: .none)
          }
      }
      func requestTitleName(){

          NetworkingService.shared.reqTitle(phone_number: user!.phone_number ?? "") { spinnerResponse in

              if (spinnerResponse == nil){

                  self.view.makeToast("Technical problem, please try again...")

              } else {

                  if (spinnerResponse?.success == Const.ResponseKey.Success){

                      print(spinnerResponse ?? "")

                      if let apiResponseData = spinnerResponse!.data{

                          self.titleName.removeAll()

                           // filtering data what I want to put
                          _ = apiResponseData.filter { (dic) -> Bool in
                              if dic.types == “Testing Request“ {

                                  self.titleName.append(dic.listName ?? "")

                              }
                              return true
                          }
                      }

                      print(self.titleName)
                      self.reloadTableView()


                  } else if (spinnerResponse?.success == Const.ResponseKey.SessionEnd) {
                      self.sessionEnd()
                  } else{

                      let popup             = PopupDialog(title: "Gagal Meminta Data ", message: spinnerResponse?.error)
                      let buttonOK          = DefaultButton(title: "OK"){

                      }
                      popup.addButton(buttonOK)

                      self.present(popup,animated: true,completion: nil)

                  }

              }
          }

      }

      func requestExtendedData() {

          print(TransactionNumber.instance.genTransNumber(_jenisTransaksi: .BANK, _phoneNumber: (user?.phone_number)!))

          NetworkingService.shared.requestExtendedDataCashin(phone_number: user!.phone_number!, jenis_trx: "VI", nama_lk: sendTitleNameForGettingExtendedData) { responseTutorial in

              if (responseTutorial == nil) {

                  self.view.makeToast("Technical problem, please try again...")
              } else {

                  if responseTutorial?.success == Const.ResponseKey.Success {

                      self.extendedData = (responseTutorial?.token)!

                      // convert into array for showing all text in responseTutorial.token
                      var delimiter = "\n"
                      self.arrayextendedData = (responseTutorial?.token!.components(separatedBy: delimiter))!

                      self.reloadTableView()

                  } else if responseTutorial?.success == Const.ResponseKey.SessionEnd {

                      self.sessionEnd()

                  } else if responseTutorial?.success == Const.ResponseKey.Error {

                      self.view.makeToast((responseTutorial?.token)!)
                  }
              }
          }
      }
}
```

How can i fix this duplicating data?
Thank you.

Comment: edit your question and add images plz

Comment: post `requestExtendedData` code

Comment: you don't use result `self.arrayextendedData = (responseTutorial?.token!.components(separatedBy: delimiter))!` inside `requestExtendedData`

Comment: @Sh_Khan I use it inside `reloadTableView()` because what i get from the response is only `String` and i can't make the `string` fully showed because it's too long...
So i think i'll make it into `array` and separated by `\n` and then i use it in `reloadTableView()`
> `sectionData`

And the result that show is:

`Testing`
`Taking`
`Data`
`From`
`Server`
`Response`

Comment: @Sh_Khan If i didn't use the `self.arrayextendedData = (responseTutorial?.token!.components(separatedBy: delimiter))!`, it'll show as `testing` `testing` `testing` `testing` `testing` `testing`

Comment: @Gagan_iOS already edited sir

Comment: @Gagan_iOS I’m really sorry about the image. I’ve update the image sir.

Comment: this is known as accordion table. Search on Google how to create accordion tableiew. or you find here https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=accordion